# Python symlink FileExistsError

Tags: python

I want to read out one folder and create symlinks of this folder in an other folder, but I get an FileExistsError: [WinError 183] file can not be created if it allready exists:  'C:\Users\Dag\Desktop\aaa\0_Data\abc' -> 'C:\Users\Dag\Desktop\aaa\3_Docs\docs'

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()


rootDir = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir="/",
                                  title='Select a root directory')
destDir = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir="/",
                                  title='Select a destination directory') 
subfolder = ''
subfolderRoot = []
i = 0
for item in os.listdir(os.path.normpath(destDir + "/")):
    subfolder = item
    i = i + 1
    print(subfolder)
    print(i)

    for item in os.listdir(os.path.normpath(rootDir + "/")):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(rootDir, item)):
            source = os.path.normpath(rootDir + "/" + item)
            link_name = os.path.normpath(destDir + '/' + subfolder + '/')
            os.symlink(source, link_name)

            print("dest: " + link_name)
            print("source: " + source)


print(subfolder)
```

[console print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7HZ7.png)

What do I wrong here?

Comment: The error is clear.  You can't create a symlink if a file of that name already exists.

Comment: I do not undersand why, when I just print it out it shows me the rigt structure - so I think.

Comment: The file `source` already exists.  You can't name a symlink the same as an existing file.

Comment: and this is the part I do not understand. Whaat have I to modify to let it work?

Comment: You have to use a different name for the symlink.  The filename `source` already exists.  Choose a different name.

Comment: I did, b ut the same result:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dag\Desktop\subfolder_read.py", line 28, in <module>
    os.symlink(link_source, link_name)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183]

Comment: Okay, I got it :)
link_name = os.path.normpath(destDir + '/' + subfolder + '/' + item)